# Heat Map with species distribution

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, spatial-statistics, heat-map

what I am trying to do is to generate a heat map depicting the spatial distribution of certain species found in a lake, in association with their sex. For example, species_a+male or species_b+female or species_a+female and so on.Also, I will be assigning unique arithmetic values to every combination, e.g. species_a+male=1, species_b+male=2 and so on, in order to use this non-spatial data. So, the question is how can I do it? I already experimented with heatmaps or the simpler Topo to Raster method but nothing seems to do the trick.

Comment: What exactly is this "heat map" intended to show, given that species (and certainly sexes) can overlap?  What form will the input take?  Could you give an example of such a map?